# how to use same style on different component with styled-components

Tags: javascript, react-native, styled-components, template-literals

i have this two component in React-native

```
const TouchableContainer = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  flex: 1;
  background-color: ${(props: any) => (props.expired ? '#ebebeb' : '#ffffff')};
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  padding-horizontal: 20px;
  padding-vertical: 12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
  shadow-color: #000;
  shadow-opacity: 0.23;
  shadow-radius: 2.62px;
  shadow-offset: 0px 3px;
  elevation: 4;
`;

const CardView = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  background-color: ${(props: any) => (props.expired ? '#ebebeb' : '#ffffff')};
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  padding-horizontal: 20px;
  padding-vertical: 12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
  shadow-color: #000;
  shadow-opacity: 0.23;
  shadow-radius: 2.62px;
  shadow-offset: 0px 3px;
  elevation: 4;
`;
```

the style is the same so this is way to factorise it : (i didn't found a solution easly so it's a working answer )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const style = `
  flex: 1;  
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  padding-horizontal: 20px;
  padding-vertical: 12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
  shadow-color: #000;
  shadow-opacity: 0.23;
  shadow-radius: 2.62px;
  shadow-offset: 0px 3px;
  elevation: 4;
`;

const TouchableContainer = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  ${style}
  background-color: ${(props: any) => (props.expired ? '#ebebeb' : '#ffffff')};
`;

const CardView = styled.View`
  ${style}
  background-color: ${(props: any) => (props.expired ? '#ebebeb' : '#ffffff')};
`;
```